# How to add a link in one team app to another team app

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a team app which will be retired in couple of month. We want to add a banner with a deep link linking to a new team app, so we add a banner in the old app with a href like:

```
<a href="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/{app_id}">
          <strong>check it out!</strong>
</a>
```

But when I click the link, it jumped into the current team app's default tab without any content; If I right click the link, select open link, it open it in the browser, asking me if I want to open MS Teams app. We don't want to either of such behaviors. Is there any way it could rout to the new team app? I can confirm the app_id is the new app's id.

Any idea what I am missing?

Update: We end up using button click event, like

```
  function handleOpen(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink(
      "msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/xxx/xxx"
    )
  }
```

Comment: Could you please confirm if your new Teams app is a custom app or it is listed in the Teams store?

Comment: It is a React App we build for our org and installed in Teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Deep link to an app isn't supported for custom apps.
You have to publish your app in Teams store to deep link that app.

Ref Issue: [Deep link to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-application?tabs=teamsjs-v2#:%7E:text=Deep%20link%20to%20an%20app%20isn%27t%20supported%20for%20custom%20apps.)